# Adding each node a different color when adding a new node to JTree

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jtree

Adding each node a different color when adding a new node to `JTree`.

```
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeModel;
import javax.swing.tree.TreeSelectionModel;

public class jtre extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public jtre() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void jButtonAddActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        DefaultMutableTreeNode selectedNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) jTree1.getSelectionPath().getLastPathComponent();
        DefaultMutableTreeNode newNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(jTextField1.getText());
        selectedNode.add(newNode);
        DefaultTreeModel model = (DefaultTreeModel) jTree1.getModel();
        model.reload();
    }

    private void jTree1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        TreeSelectionModel smd = jTree1.getSelectionModel();
        if (smd.getSelectionCount() > 0) {
            DefaultMutableTreeNode selectedNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) jTree1.getSelectionPath().getLastPathComponent();
            jTextField1.setText(selectedNode.getUserObject().toString());
        }
    }

    private void jButtonEditActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        DefaultMutableTreeNode selectedNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) jTree1.getSelectionPath().getLastPathComponent();
        selectedNode.setUserObject(jTextField1.getText());
        DefaultTreeModel model = (DefaultTreeModel) jTree1.getModel();
        model.reload();
    }

    private void jButtonRemoveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        DefaultMutableTreeNode selectedNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) jTree1.getSelectionPath().getLastPathComponent();
        if (selectedNode != jTree1.getModel().getRoot()) {
            DefaultTreeModel model = (DefaultTreeModel) jTree1.getModel();
            model.removeNodeFromParent(selectedNode);
            model.reload();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new jtre().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    private javax.swing.JButton jButtonAdd;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButtonEdit;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButtonRemove;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JTree jTree1;
}
```

When the add button is clicked the new node of the tree will be added with a different color. How can I make it?

Comment: What color and how is the color of each node determined? Also, *why?*

Comment: Nodes representing the logical and operation can be red, or the nodes representing the operation can be blue. We're trying to convert this tree to a foda chart, so we're going to colorize the and - or operations on the tree.

Comment: We want to build foda chart by using Jtree . We are going to convert Jtree to foda chart . In foda chart , there is  and - or - exclusive or operations. We are going to represent and -or operations by using colorful Jtree. and operations will represent red color , or operations represent blue color. Please help my code. I need a help. Thank you.

Comment: I don't see anything [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=foda+chart&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&biw=1246&bih=960&dpr=1) that looks like a `JTree` or anything easily adaptable from a `JTree`. But whatevs.. If the objects being used as tree nodes encapsulate the information needed to distinguish between the two types, use a [`TreeCellRenderer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/tree/TreeCellRenderer.html). At the top of those docs is a link to the relevant section of the tutorial.

Comment: `jTree1MouseClicked` BTW - better to use a `TreeSelectionListener` rather than a `MouseListener`, for a `JTree`.

Comment: We couldn t find foda chart plotting tool.so We want to use jtree and We convert  it as a foda chart plotting tool. How can i colored  jtree 's each node. Please  Write a useable code  for me.

Comment: Pleas edit your question to include new requirements; see also [_SWOT_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SWOT_analysis); I'd use a grid or gridbag layout or a [tag:jfreechart] bubble plot.